# Imaginary Numbers in AC analysis

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, ac

Why is 1/j = -j?

I keep seeing capacitor voltages that look like $$ i * 1/j \omega C$$ which then become $$-j*i/ \omega C$$.

I get that we can apply that 1/j = -j, but why is this relationship true?

Comment: not really even an EE question: that's pretty much answerable with the defintiion of \$j\$. See transistor's answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to math.SE

Answer (score 11):

$$ \frac 1 j = \frac 1 j \frac j j = \frac j {j^2}= \frac j {-1} = -j $$

Comment: Good heavens, I just realized it must be about 40 years ago since I last saw that at school.

Comment: Same for me. It was a memory check. Pass, I think!

Comment: Yes, QC passed.